# proposition with quantifier 5

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I was asked to give an example of a proposition with a quantifier which is true if the quantifier ranges over the integers, but false if it ranges over the rational numbers.

My attempt:

$(\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, n^2\geq n)$

Is this what the question is looking for?

Comment: Your example is perfect. Plus one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example,

$$(\forall (n,p)\in \Bbb N^2)\;\; p\notin (n,n+1)$$

this is not true in $\Bbb Q$ since it is dense.

Comment: Thank you, so mine is not correct?

Comment: @Forextrader Yours is correct.